# Angular-UI-Layout collapse speed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Is it possible to change the animation speed with which a layout page is collapsed? Currently, I am using the following snippet to create a layout with two panes:

```
 <div ui-layout="{flow: 'column'}">
        <div ui-layout-container>Hello</div>
        <div ui-layout-container>World</div>
 </div>
```